# Resource Hacker Show and Enable Hidden button always

Tags: dll

I have a page setup window for crystal reports that doesn't play nice in Win7/2008R2 and I thought maybe I could use resource hacker to modify the dialog to always show the said button. But I am not to functional on resource hacker, usually just use for icon extraction.

Any direction or good reference on what I might need to do to enable this?

This is the line in the dialog that I see controlling that button that always stays hidden. I know the function for the button actually works, using showwin.exe I can repaint the hidden button and click it.

```
CONTROL "&Printer...", 1026, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 176, 219, 48, 14
```

I just am not sure what to do from here.

Thanks!